# npm install ERROR in WARN

Tags: php, node.js, npm, cmd, npm-install

For my Laravel course, I need to install npm. 
To install npm, I had to go to nodejs.org, installed it. Then in cmd, I write `npm install` 
and then I got this error-

> ```
> npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\xampp\htdocs\package.json'
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\xampp\htdocs\package.json'
> npm WARN htdocs No description
> npm WARN htdocs No repository field.
> npm WARN htdocs No README data
> npm WARN htdocs No license field.
> ```

What to do with this?

Comment: search what npm install does first. You might need to download some code with a file called package.json

Comment: If you have existing project then check :
Do you have file in **C:\xampp\htdocs\package.json** location? May be you are no at your porject location ie.  **C:\xampp\htdocs\<project_name>\package.json**

If you want to initialise it then go to project folder and perform **npm init**

Answer (score 1):

`npm install` is used to install the required modules that will be used in your application.

It uses the `package.json` file to know which modules need to be installed and run.

In you case it seems there is no `package.json` file created. So you have to create a `package.json` file first, using the command `npm init`.

Go into your main directory and run the preceding command, follow the steps like enter the application name, ...etc. and the file will be created.

Then use the `npm install` command to install any module you wish to, and the `package.json` will be updated and will keep track of the modules installed in your application.

Comment: I did this and that is showing to me-
"npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file."
up to date in 0.109s

Comment: in the last "npm install" command  "npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file." is not shown, but I can't even find "node modules" folder in my project.

how can ii solve this?

Comment: By the way, Thank you after a long time